# How to check if a flash drive is bootable using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I want to check if the flash drive is bootable with a PowerShell.

I tried to use **(Get-Disk).PartitionStyle**, **win32_diskpartition.Bootable** and **win32_diskpartition.BootPartition** 
- it does not reflect the real situation, they are based on the Partition Style (MBR or GPT).

I have two flash drives, one with a Windows 10 image, the second is empty. 
But both of it has the MBR boot sector type. WMI classes also show that "Bootable" is "True".

Is there any other way to find if the flash drive is bootable?

Answer (score 0):

Try  to use this commands to get boot disk, test at 4 flash drives and it works

```
Get-Disk |Where-Object {$_.IsBoot -eq $true -and $_.BootFromDisk -eq $true}
```

**Additional**
I checked it and was only half right. On usb drives, by default there is a sector that is responsible for the boot disk flag(may it stay if usb was once bootable and not deleted then).

Comment: This parameter shows whether the system is currently was booted from this disk.

Comment: Then why it works for my flash drives that are bootable and dont work for another flash drives?

Comment: These options will be "true" for flash drivers only when I load Windows from my flash drive.